Do Ethernet Switches have MAC Addresses?
I live in a dormitory and am attempting to set up an Ethernet switch. The only issue is that my dormitory requires we register each device's 'ID' when we connect over Ethernet.
Do Ethernet switches have a device ID? How do I find out what it is?
The note on our device registration page:

To add a new device, enter the device ID, which displays on your
device as the MAC or Wi-Fi address. It consists of 6 alphanumeric
number pairs separated by colons such as AA:BB:CC:11:22:33.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Most likely you should register the MAC address of every "endpoint" device (such as phone, tablet and laptop) connected the switch. The only exception would be a router connected to the switch or the wall socket provided, assuming that is even allowed. (You probably don't need to register "pure" wireless AP, if any, even if it has a MAC address, but it really depends on what would be done when unregistered device is detected.)

If it does then there is a label with it printed on it. We need more information before anyone could possibly answer your question

What is the model number of the Ethernet switch? An unmanaged layer 2 switch won't have a MAC address.

You left out a ton of details about your ethernet switch, the campus ethernet switch you wish to attach to, and the campus FAQ or policy document for connecting.
The EthernetV2 blue book specification makes it pretty clear
that when a vendor manufactures an ethernet device it
must display a unique 48-bit MAC address label in a visible place,
such as near the ether cable connection port.
Examine your device and read the label.

Do Ethernet switches have a device ID? How do I find out what it is?

Yes.
A "transparent" layer-2 bridge should emit
STP BPDUs.
The idea is to avoid bridge loops.
If you plug in a triangle of devices, or similar cycle,
it's likely that each ether frame sent on one segment
will loop around to be re-sent on that segment,
and then re-sent infinitely often.
The segment "melts", it overloads, and cannot transport
any new traffic, at least not with a usefully low drop rate.
Layer-3 loops (during route table convergence) are less troublesome as
the TTL will decrement to zero, letting an IP router discard the looping packet.
Connect a host to your layer-2 bridge and use tcpdump or WireShark
to observe those multicast BPDUs.
Report the source MAC addr to your campus network administrator.
Of course, if I was that admin, I would announce a policy of "no bridges!",
as they lead to too much disruption and troubleshooting effort.
And I would configure the switch port in your dorm to disconnect
if it saw Spanning Tree BPDUs, or if it saw more than just a single
distinct source MAC addr coming from that port.
Review the campus policy document to see if your desired config is a supported one.

If I were the admin, I would also have a policy of only one MAC address per (campus) switch port (for wired ethernet). This is one of those situations were a tiny ethernet router with NAT would be useful because it looks like one device - I use a GL.iNet GL-MT3000 (no affiliation) to get around this type of restriction, incl. for WiFi hotspots that only allow "one device".
